# Grails save without cascade

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

I would like to perform something but I keep finding only the oppsosite of what i want.

I have an object B that belongs to A, yet Sometimes I would like to save A WITHOUT saving B.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: When `B belongs to A` then A is the parent and B is the child. Generally, the FK constraint is added to the child table as a column referring back to A. Now I do not understand how persisting A should affect B in any case unless we want to add a record for B. In that case, record B has to make sure that Parent record in A is available. May be some code added to the question will help understand what is the requirement.

Comment: How do you know `B` is being saved? Is its `version` being updated (which would indicate that it's being saved)? Unless `B` has changed, I don't see why GORM would save it.